# setting top and left with offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to position an element using offset() but I'm not sure what is going on:
This is default offset position:

```
    element.offset().top
    ‌770
    element.offset().left
    ‌1822.796875
```

Then I try setting it manually

```
element.offset({top: 674, left: 1722 })
```

And the output:

```
element.offset().top
‌-1341
element.offset().left
 1722
```

Top position is -1341 ? and then I tried setting just top property:

```
element.offset({top:674})
element.offset().top
‌674
```

and this works ? What is going on, why I can't set both properties at the same time?

UPDATE: I just figured that this might be important: there is also iframe element on the page that has a scrollbar. So everything with offfset work fine, until I scroll down the window of the iframe element. But after scrolling down and then  calling offset() it works.

Comment: `element.css({top: '674px', left: '1722px' })`

Comment: @LShetty when supplying an integer value `px` is the assumed unit.

Comment: @LShetty syntax of OP seems to look fine as it is. Zed this looks interesting, can u make a fiddle which reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: @Rory, Jaak - Yes, my bad!

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/ps3wy0sf/ The problem is in code that you're not showing us. Try to come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I second @Juhana, is there something else affecting the position of this element?

Comment: read the update please.

Comment: You still need to show an example. Otherwise it's pretty much impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no shared fiddle, I'm assuming your scenario.
Assuming your element is hidden and you are setting its offset and then making it as visible. in this case your offset settings will not work.

Try to follow these steps.

1. Make that element visible. (maybe by using element.show())
2. Set the offset now.